# Why does Visual Studio treat folders as projects?

Tags: visual-studio, solution

I've got a Visual Studio solution structured like so (simplified):

```
Root Folder
|   Solution.sln
|   
+---Build
|
+---Code
|   +---Business Layer
|   |   |   Business Layer.csproj
|   +---Client
|   |   |   Client.csproj
|   |           
|   +---Data Access Layer
|   |   |   Data Access Layer.csproj
|   |
|   +---Database
|   |   |   Database.sqlproj
|   |
|   \---Database User Management
|       |   Database User Management.pssproj
|
+---Documentation
|
+---Packages
|                
+---Tests
```

The tl;dr here is that all of my projects are stored under 2 separate folders. Code for... well the program code and Tests for the unit test projects.

However, in my .sln file, I've noticed these lines:

```
Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = "Code", "Code", "{2C7E59FD-BA42-4D31-A5E0-818583B7E1EC}"
EndProject
Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = "Tests", "Tests", "{1D1FDB9D-78EC-4552-B9EE-17E02E92FC2E}"
EndProject
```

These folders aren't projects, they're only for organising the projects so that I'm not mixing my unit test projects with the actual software projects.

Removing these lines from the .sln file basically puts all my projects under one node in the Solution Explorer tree, but seems to keep the folder structure.

What's also odd is it's only doing it for the Code and Tests Folders and not Documentation and Packages.

Is this how Visual Studio is supposed to organise projects?

EDIT: To answer why I'm even bothering to tinker with the .sln file. When I open it in Visual Studio it says it's got 8 projects to load, which is odd, since at the moment there's only 5. (x3 .csproj, x1 .pssproj and x1 .sqlproj)

Comment: Please don't ever become a doctor. "What's all this stuff doing in here? I'm just going to scoop it out. Why is it even needed?"

Comment: I've got no intention of becoming one, so I think we're safe there. ;-) I'm just trying to understand how VS is marking these folders as projects, but not others.

Comment: Eh, that's the way it is.  The guid for that project type 2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8 is for folders.  You can search for it and maybe find more info.  Might have been a hack to support folders a long time ago, and they never changed it.  Who knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's simply how Visual Studio solution file format works. Though displaying between `Project` and `EndProject`, a folder is still a folder.

Comment: So why would my other folders not be marked in the same way? Something to do with not having projects in them maybe? Documentation for example is filled with hundreds of markdown documents and packages just has assemblies from Nuget. These assemblies and markdown files are also nested a few levels deep.

Comment: http://blog.bfitz.us/?p=955 posts like this can give you more insights. You can even now see MSBuild source code and learn how it parses solution files, https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/1510d9a8cf346f01919c5b9545ef0b1a25bfbe9d/src/XMakeBuildEngine/Construction/Solution/SolutionFile.cs

Comment: Aaaand... it makes almost perfect sense now after reading that link on Github. Thanks.